# jQuery alert box with PHP file manipulation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am trying to solve this but I can't figure this out.I know less about jQuery and Javascript so any help will be helpful.
Specifically, I want to build jQuery code to alert a message to user(when he hits 'submit' button).
I have created 2 individual php files(1st is user_form.php and the 2nd insert.php)

user_form.php :

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="insert.php">

 <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">card</label>
 <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="card_number" required></div>
                            </div>


   <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">name</label>
 <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required></div>
                            </div>

               <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
       <button class="btn btn-primary demo1 type="submit">submit</button>
                             </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>
```

insert.php:

```
$stmt_select3 = $conn->prepare("SELECT `card_number`, `card_store_id`, `active` FROM `card` WHERE `card_number`=$card_number;");
$stmt_select3->execute();

if($stmt_select3->rowCount()==1){


    while($row_select3 = $stmt_select3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){


                if($row_select3['card_store_id'] != $_SESSION['store_id'] && $row_select3['active']=0){
                            header("Location:message1.html");}


                }else if($row_select3['card_store_id'] != $_SESSION['store_id'] && $row_select3['active']=1){
                            header("Location:message1.html");}




                }else if($row_select3['card_store_id'] == $_SESSION['store_id'] && $row_select3['active']=1){
                            header("Location:message3.html");}

                            };

}else  {
    header("Location:message.html");

       }
```

I think it is right.
So I want to create a button alert running on user_form.php, getting data from insert.php and the message on the box will be depended on 'if' statement each time.
Any notice will be appreciateful and helpful!

Comment: I tried with jQuery a lot of times but I couldn't have a good result.But I don't mind, I would use javascript also.

Comment: I think but it can be done using a combination of jQuery and Ajax but I am not aware of these client-side programming languages.